# Applicaton Splash Screen Opacity is not right

Tags: android

activity_splash.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgLogo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@drawable/language"
    android:alpha="0.2"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="TRANSLO"
    android:textColor="#191970"
    android:textSize="40dp"/>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="159dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Code For Splash Screen for the application i am expecting image to be little bit dull than the application name but all stuff gets dark

[This is the splash screen i am getting when i run my code which is quiet dark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pf9JF.jpg)

Comment: Based on your XML code, the output looks right.  Try different color (white for TRANSLO) and check, as you can see your progress bar is well lit as it should be.

Comment: the color choices you have are quite awful as a design.... but yes, the blue color is right, you are just having black and a dark blue.

Comment: i am not concerned about the color i am concerned about brightness of the screen of output